# Using WithConstructorArgument and creating bound type

Tags: ninject, ninject-2

I have a binding that looks like this:

```
kernel.Bind<IRepository<Holiday>>().To<RepositoryBase<Holiday>>();
```

The problem is that RepositoryBase takes a contructor paramter of UnitOfWork called context.  This is not, in and of itself a problem.  Ninject should resolve it.  Except for the fact that I have two UnitOfWork implementations, both bound using an attribute discriminator.

```
kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<MS_DevEntities>().WhenTargetHas<MsDataAttribute>()
    .InRequestScope();
```

How can specify that when an IRepository is created, it should be created with MS_DevEntities?

Certainly, i could do something like this:

```
kernel.Bind<IRepository<Holiday>>().To<RepositoryBase<Holiday>>()
    .WithConstructorArgument("context", new MS_DevEntities());
```

However, I would prefer to have Ninject create the instance, particularly because i'm using the .InRequestScope() lifecycle.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

Previously, I was using a class that looked like this:

```
public class HolidayRepository : RepositoryBase<Holiday>, IHolidayRepository
{
    public HolidayRepository([MsData]IUnitOfWork context) : base(context){}
}
```

However, I now find myself with several dozen of these and they don't do much but add extra work when I need to create a new repository.  I'd like to just map these directly in the bindings.

EDIT2:

I suppose I could do something like this, but it seems kind of hackish.  Is there a better way?

```
kernel.Bind<MS_DevEntities>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
kernel.Bind<IRepository<Holiday>>().To<RepositoryBase<Holiday>>()
    .WithConstructorArgument("context", 
        (context) => context.Kernel.Get<MS_DevEntities>());
```

Comment: Do I understand this correctly? You have a binding for all types e.g IRepository<Holiday> and no generic binding IRepository<> and for some of those types you want UoW1 and for others UoW2? Or what is the criteria for taking UoW1 or UoW2 in case of the repositories? An attribute on the entity?

Comment: @RemoGloor - Can you bind generalically to all specialized types in Ninject?  If so, that's really cool.  But no, I have no generic binding.  I am specifically binding all my IRepository<T> types, and i need to specify which UoW to use for each of them.  I was using the attribute to select the correct binding in derived classes, but they were just adding more work for no good reason when i'm adding no extra code to my repository other than the generic base.

Comment: @RemoGloor - See edit above for example of what i'm trying to duplicate in a binding.

Comment: What's the criteria then to specify which repository gets which UoW? E.g. attribute on the entity, config file/class, ...?

Comment: Just in case you're not aware, there are some examples that might give you ideas on [the ninject wiki contextual bindingpage](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding)

Comment: @RemoGloor - Well, that's just it.  I used an attribute previously on my concrete implementation (as per my edit).  But since my concrete implementation will now be generic, i can't do that. I want to just use a mapping similar to the .WithConstructorArgument, but resolve the type in the binding.  What are my options?

Comment: @RubenBartelink - Unfortunately, all those examples use attributes or similar changes to the concrete classes to indicate the context.  I can't do that in this case because the Concrete class is generic, and takes a different parameter depending on which specialization it is.  I was using these techniques previously, but this requires something a little different.

Comment: @RemoGloor - Is there any way to tell Ninject to inject an attribute into the constructor parameter, so that it will be resolved correctly?  ie. can I tell Ninject to inject the MsData attribute into the constructor parameter named "context" of IRepositoryBase<Holiday>, PRIOR to resolving the constructor parameters arguments? Then ninject can just go about it's business normally?

Comment: No - Attributes have to be added at compile time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

E.g. Put the attribute to the entity and use something like this:

```
kernel.Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(RepositoryBase<>));
kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<MS_DevEntities>()
      .When(r => EntityHas<MsData>(r));
kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<TheOtherOne_DevEntities>()
      .When(r => EntityHas<TheOtherData>(r));

bool EntityHas<TAttribute>(IRequest r)
{
    return r.Target.Member.ReflectedType.IsGenericType &&
           r.Target.Member.ReflectedType.GetGenericArguments()[0]
               .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttribute), false).Any();
}
```

You can do everything using this `When` condition and take the entity type from `r.Target.Member.ReflectedType.GetGenericArguments()[0]` to lookup somewhere which UoW that you have to use for this entity type.

2nd approch using config

```
kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<TheOtherOne_DevEntities>()
      .When(r => EntityNeedsUoW(r, 1));

bool EntityNeedsUoW(IRequest r, int id)
{
    return UoWConfig.GetDbIdForEntity(
         r.Target.Member.ReflectedType.GetGenericArguments()[0]) == id;
}
```

Comment: I'd go with what I proposed. Just write a When condition that fits for you. E.g. doo a lookup in a configuration file/class, add the attribute like I proposed or whatever fits for you.

Comment: That's an interesting thought, I didn't really think about using attributes on the entity.  Only problem is that my entities are generated by T4 template, and that would mean creating partial classes for all of them, which again is a huge maintenenace headache.  Something to think about though.

Comment: See update. As I said find a "When" that fits for you. I can't give you more help though. You need to find your prefered way.