# Inject different classes that implement the same interface using Ninject

Tags: c#, ninject

I am implementing the builder design pattern to construct different kinds of graph objects to be displayed on a WPF UI. I am using Ninject as my IOC container. However, I am trying to find an elegant extendable solution.

I have a `ChartDirector` object that takes a `IChartBuilder` as a dependency. I also have `TemperatureChartBuilder` and `ThresholdChartBuilder` that implement `IChartBuilder`. I want to inject either `TemperatureChartBuilder` OR `ThresholdChartBuilder` to `ChartDirector` depending on an event that is fired or depending on a client call. I have illustrated my problem below in code.

```
// ChartDirector also depends on this
kernel.Bind<IExample>().To<Example>();

// when called in Method X...
kernel.Bind<IChartBuilder>().To<TemperatureChartBuilder>();

// when called in Method Y...
kernel.Bind<IChartBuilder>().To<ThresholdChartBuilder();

// TemperatureChartBuilder is a dependency of ChartDirector, need a way to dynamically
// allocate which binding to use.
var director = kernel.Get<ChartDirector>();

// without Ninject I would do
var director = new ChartDirector(new TemperatureChartBuilder);

// or
var director = new ChartDirector(new ThresholdChartBuilder);
```

EDIT:

Coupled with Gary's answer, and noting a slight edit that ChartDirector has another dependency, I now want to do something like this:

```
var director = kernel.Get<ChartDirector>().WithConstructorArgument(kernel.Get<IChartBuilder>("TemperatureChart"));
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 15):

If you're just planning to use service location, as in your examples, then named bindings work fine, as per Garys answer.

A better approach, however, is to use constructor injection, and use attributes.  For exampl, from the ninject wiki:

```
Bind<IWeapon>().To<Shuriken>().Named("Strong");
Bind<IWeapon>().To<Dagger>().Named("Weak");
```

...

```
class WeakAttack {
    readonly IWeapon _weapon;
    public([Named("Weak")] IWeapon weakWeapon)
        _weapon = weakWeapon;
    }
    public void Attack(string victim){
        Console.WriteLine(_weapon.Hit(victim));
    }
}
```

Based on your comment to Gary, you're (strangely enough) stumbling into territory similar to what I asked a question about a few hours ago.  See Remo's answer here: [Using WithConstructorArgument and creating bound type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580071/)

You would use When condition to define when to create the correct instance.

Comment: So your injection target assembly has to carry around a reference to Ninject just to enable the `NamedAttribute`?  That doesn't seem right.

Comment: @rory.ap - Well, there will always be concessions, as this is not easy behavior to implement transparently.

Answer (score 9):

I would suggest using Contextual bindings (named bindings specifically) to accomplish this. That way you can do something like:

```
// called on app init
kernel.Bind<IChartBuilder>().To<TemperatureChartBuilder>().Named("TempChartBuilder");   
kernel.Bind<IChartBuilder>().To<ThresholdChartBuilder().Named("ThreshChartBuilder");

// method X/Y could both call method Z that grabs the correct chart director
var director = new ChartDirector(kernel.Get<IChartBuilder>("TempChartBuilder"));
```

Where "TempChartBuilder" could be a variable that tells ninject which binding to resolve. So rather binding on the fly you would resolve on the fly but all binding could be defined up front. Typically IOC containers are stored at the application domain level and only need to be defined once. There may be specific cases where you need to bind dynamically but those should be rare.

More info on contextual bindings: https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding

Comment: +1 as very helpful. One thing I didn't mention in my original question was that ChartBuilder has other dependencies specified during App initialisation, therefore ninject automatically injects the other required dependencies when I call kernel.Get<ChartDirector>. So is there a way of doing what you suggested with `kernel.Get<ChartDirector>` and injecting the correct chartbuilder for each specific Get?

Comment: @Seth - You may want to look at creating two different ninject modules that contain only the specific bindings you want to resolve - https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Modules-and-the-Kernel. I would also take a look at the dynamic factory/provider model that ninject provides - https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Providers,-Factory-Methods-and-the-Activation-Context

Comment: can you look at my edit - I'm not sure if your suggestions in your last comment address the last component of my question.. appreciate your help so far :)