# Autofac inject specific implemenation into home controller

Tags: autofac

This is first time I am using autofac & mvc 4.
I have installed AutoFac using Nuget package.
My nuget package installed:

```
<package id="Autofac" version="3.1.5" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Autofac.Mvc4" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
```

I have three implementations of my logger:

```
 builder.RegisterType<DbLogger>().As<ILogger>();
 builder.RegisterType<TextLogger>().As<ILogger>();
 builder.RegisterType<MemoryLogger>().As<ILogger>();
```

My home controller is registered using following code:

```
// in case we want to exclude this in external dll
builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());
```

My Home controller constructor for All three implementations is easy:

```
private ILogger[] loggers;
public HomeController(ILogger[] loggers)
{
  this.loggers = loggers;
}
```

**How do I register specific "MemoryLogger" into my MemoryController?**

```
 private ILogger _memoryLogger;
        public MemoryController(ILogger logger)
        {
            this._memoryLogger = logger;
        }
```

I know that I can re-register controller with specific implementation.

same as for Ninject

[Inject different classes that implement the same interface using Ninject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585325/inject-different-classes-that-implement-the-same-interface-using-ninject)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution has been quite simple:

```
const string loggerImplementation = "DbLoggerForMemoryController";

builder.RegisterType<DbLogger>().As<ILogger>().Named<ILogger>(loggerImplementation);
builder.RegisterType<TextLogger>().As<ILogger>();            
builder.RegisterType<MemoryLogger>().As<ILogger>();

builder.Register(x => new MemoryController(x.ResolveNamed<ILogger>(loggerImplementation)));
```

I just hope it will save time to everyone else :)
If you have better solution, please share it.

Comment: What if you would have several dependencies in MemoryController?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Metadata feature. You can find more info on [wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/Metadata).

Comment: Thnx, but this is the last option I would like to use, as this is providing definition into code, in which case i could use MEF instead. I want to be able to configure it all on config level. Still thnx for suggestion.